# error TS2339: Property 'deviceXDPI' does not exist on type 'Screen'

Tags: typescript

I have some code like this

```js
if (window.screen.deviceXDPI) {
  arrDPI[0] = window.screen.deviceXDPI;
  arrDPI[1] = window.screen.deviceYDPI;
}
```

then i got the compile error

```
error TS2339: Property 'deviceXDPI' does not exist on type 'Screen'.
```

I try to modify like this but still got the same error

```js
const { deviceXDPI, deviceYDPI } = window.screen as any

if (deviceXDPI) {
  arrDPI[0] = deviceXDPI;
  arrDPI[1] = deviceYDPI;
}
```

typescript version is 3.2.4